# Invalid session id when calling sendKeys() in Selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, cucumberjs

UPDATE: Figured out what my issue was, you have to return a promise on every step for selenium to work. So I added `return el.sendKeys()` from my page function and also returned from the step definition and it worked.

I'm using Selenium, Chromedriver, and Cucumber js to test a react application. I'm able to click on an element without issue but when I attempt to send keys for a text input or dropdown it does not work and I get this warning:

```
NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id
From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
```

I've tried a lot of different things including making the function async, setting different chrome options, and pausing before quitting the driver but haven't had any luck.

Here's my world.js

```
const seleniumWebdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
var pageLoader = require('./pageLoader.js')
const {setWorldConstructor, setDefaultTimeout} = require('@cucumber/cucumber')
var config = require('../../config.json')

class CustomWorld {
  constructor() {
    this.driver = new seleniumWebdriver
      .Builder()
      .forBrowser(config.browser)
      .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().headless())
      .build()
    pageLoader.load(this)
  }
}

setDefaultTimeout(config.timeout);
setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld);
```

My hooks.js

```
const fs = require('fs')
var config = require('../../config.json')


Before(function() {
  return this.driver.manage().window().maximize();
})

After(function (scenario, callback) {
  if(scenario.result.status === Status.FAILED){
    this.driver.takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
      var screenshotPath = config.screenshotFolder + scenario.pickle.name + '.png'
      fs.writeFileSync(screenshotPath, data, 'base64');
    });
  }
  this.driver.quit().then(function () {
    callback();
  });
});
```

Cucumber scenario

```
  Scenario: Add New Rule
    Given I am on the app
    And I click the Add Rule button
    When I set the following values for the Rule Builder
      | name   |
      | example|
```

Step definitions

```
Given(/^I am on the app$/, function () {
  return this.homePage.open()
})

Given(/^I click the Add Rule button$/, function () {
  return this.homePage.clickAddRule()
})

When(/^I set the following values for the Rule Builder$/, function (table) {
  const table_hash = table.hashes()[0]
  for (const entry in table_hash){
    this.createRulePage[entry](table_hash[entry])
  }
})
```

home.page.js

```
const HomePage = Object.create(Page, {
  open: {
    value () {
      return this.browser.get('http://localhost:3000/')
    }
  },

  clickAddRule: {
    value () {
      return this.browser.findElement(By.css("button.c-button")).click()
    }
  }
})

module.exports = HomePage
```

createRule.page.js

```
const CreateRulePage = Object.create(Page, {
  name: {
    value(name) {
      var el = this.browser.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("[data-testid='name']")), 1000)
      el.clear()
      el.click()
      el.send(name)

    }
  }
})

module.exports = CreateRulePage
```

I've read through about 100 so posts trying to find a solution but can't seem to get anything to  work. Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: this error suggests that the driver has quit or is in the process of quitting when you tried to use a webdriver method.   Hard to tell why this is happening without seeing the context of when you call the "value" function.   Possibly due to After being called when it shouldn't be?

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for the reply! I'm calling the function after clicking on an element which opens a modal so maybe it's quitting after the click? I updated the post to give more context.